# how to display last modified on time and date without GMT

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

currently is displaying like this Thu Feb 22 06:50:52 GMT 2018

below is my code.

```
   <apex:pageBlock><apex:pageblockTable value="{!recordlist}" var="rec"><apex:column><apex:column headerValue="Last Modified" value="{!rec.LastModifiedDate}"/></apex:pageBlockTable></apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `apex:outputField` this field automatially convert your date into current login user timezone

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!recordlist}" var="rec">
        <apex:column headerValue="Last Modified" >
            <apex:outoputField value="{!rec.LastModifiedDate}"/
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```